# Chat app: What to do on successful re-connection to the WebSocket server?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-redux, chat

My friend and I are currently building a web-based chat app with WebSocket. I'm in charge of client side (React + Redux). Golang is used for the server side (I don't know whether this is a good combination, but I do this just for fun).

Basically my problem is that I don't know what to do after the successful re-connection to the WebSocket server.

More concretely:

The client side tries to reconnect to the server when the connection is lost. My questions are

1. When the re-connection is successful, what should I do with the data that were supposed to be sent to the server, but actually weren't sent because of the lost connection? Is it better to have something like a buffer to store all the data that are not yet transmitted to the server?
2. Currently, a React component do the initial fetch of all the necessary data ( rooms, friends, chat history, etc.) on `componentDidMount`. For the app to be in sync with the server on successful re-connection, the app should perform actions similar to the initial fetch. But calling `componentDidMount` deliberately does not seem to be a good idea, because it is not supposed to be called in this way. Is it good to perform initial fetching in `componentDidMount` in the first place?

Comment: Is there any possibility to share the repo? I am interested in knowing how to wire Golang and React together and what you're doing can be of a huge help. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinGhaboosi https://github.com/shirasudon/ By the way we have not finished the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is is a general question, I will answer in general terms:

1. You need some kind of buffer between the application and the unreliable stream. Since you're reactive, you can implement this using an observable. The service that is responsible for the actual communication over WebSocket will subscribe to this feed.
2. Separate the initialization of the component from initialization of the data. If you're communicating over WebSocket, you can reinitialize data every time the socket connects.

Comment: thanks for you fast reply. Regarding the second answer: I use normal HTTP connection on the initial fetch instead of WebSocket.  So, to initialize data on every socket connection, should I use WebSocket even on initial fetch?

Comment: It doesn't really matter; if you believe that your initial data is ok still after a reconnection, you don't even need to refetch it. If it is not, you can go with the websocket's connect event and fetch using any method.

Answer (score 1):

Go is certainly a good choice for the chat server because of the way it handles concurrency. The other common option for chat servers is Erlang. React is a matter of personal preference.

1. You probably don't want to buffer it all. You just want to buffer the messages but not, for instance, typing indicators because they make no sense if not sent immediately. Something as simple as an array with `push()` and `shift()` would do.
2. Move data fetching to a separate function, then call it both from `componentDidMount` and from the callback or whatever place where you reconnect.

Using both HTTP and websocket in one app is a matter of design. It does seem to complicate things though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you think, when it comes to server side rendering, it is the best to build both client and server side with Javascript (NodeJS) ? I know there is a Golang package with server side rendering feature, but I think it is still better to use NodeJS because you can simply share some codes between client and server side. Is it simply a performance reason why Golang and Erlang are often used in chat app?